# How to move files between servers with PubKey authentication?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

I have two servers and for both I'm using PubKey authentication only. Can I somehow scp files between them (with private key being only on my local machine?) ? Can I somehow use my private key for authenticating login from another machine?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ssh -A` or setup the equivalent in your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file (on your local machine:

```
 -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This
         can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration
         file.

         Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
         ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
         agent's UNIX-domain socket) can access the local agent through
         the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key mate‐
         rial from the agent, however they can perform operations on the
         keys that enable them to authenticate using the identities
         loaded into the agent.
```

In your `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` you would add/set:

```
ForwardAgent yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you're looking for what's called SSH Agent Forwarding. GitHub has a good overview page on this feature, titled: [Using ssh agent forwarding](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding).

*excerpt*

> SSH agent forwarding is a technique you can use to make deploying to a remote server simpler for you and your developers. It allows you to use you local SSH keys instead of leaving passphrase-less keys sitting on your server.
>
> If you've already set up an SSH key, you're probably familiar with ssh-agent. This is an app that runs in the background and keeps your key loaded into memory so you do not have to enter your passphrase every time you need to use the key. The nifty thing is, you can selectively let remote servers access your local ssh-agent as if it was running on the server. This is sort of like asking a friend to enter their password so you can use their computer.

On the system you're SSH'ing from you can setup a `$HOME/.ssh/config` file where you can allow the forwarding to occur.

```
Host example.com
  ForwardAgent yes
```

The servers at the other end also need to allow it, so you'll need to make sure that `AllowAgentForwarding` is set in the `sshd_config` file.

Consult the GitHub tutorial for more on setting this up and debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

ssh has the  `-A` option to forward authetication (your private key to server A [held in memory] so that you can authenticate further onto server B).

From the ssh manual page.

> -A      Enables forwarding of the authentication agent connection.  This
>                can also be specified on a per-host basis in a configuration
>                file.
>
> ```
>          Agent forwarding should be enabled with caution.  Users with the
>          ability to bypass file permissions on the remote host (for the
>          agent's Unix-domain socket) can access the local agent through
>          the forwarded connection.  An attacker cannot obtain key material
>          from the agent, however they can perform operations on the keys
>          that enable them to authenticate using the identities loaded into
>          the agent.
> ```

Check that this is alowed by config `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` `ForwardAgent Yes`